# Code coverage is 70% and I get a DUPLICATE_VALUE issue

Tags: trigger, opportunity, code-coverage, id, duplicate-management

Code coverage is 70% and when I dive into the problems I get a duplicate error.  Please help I am new to writing triggers.  Thank you ahead of time!

Problem on several Lines Message:

> [object Object]: duplicate value found: ScopeId duplicates value on record with id:

Trigger

```
trigger checkForCompetitors on Opportunity (before update) {
Set<Id> closedLostOppIds = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> oppsHavingCompetitors = new Set<Id>();

 // fetch all the Opportunity Id's that have been closed
 for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new)
 {
      if(trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != 'Closed Lost'
         && (opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost'))
      {
            closedLostOppIds.add(opp.Id);
      }
 }

 // fetch Opportunity Id's that have been Closed Lost and have a Competitor
 for(OpportunityCompetitor oc : [Select OpportunityId From OpportunityCompetitor Where OpportunityId IN : closedLostOppIds ])
 {
      oppsHavingCompetitors.add(oc.OpportunityId);
 }

 // compare the two sets (one has Closed Lost opportunity id's and other has Closed Lost opps having a competitor)
 // Left out opp's should not be allowed to close, so we throw an error.
 for(Opportunity o : trigger.new)
 {
       if(closedLostOppIds.contains(o.Id) && !oppsHavingCompetitors.contains(o.Id))
            o.addError('At least one competitor is required before closing this Opportunity');
 }}
```

Test Class

```
private class Test_checkForCompetitors {
static testMethod void checkForCompetitors() {


// Create a test account
  Account testAcct = new Account (Name = 'My Test Account');
  insert testAcct;

  // Create a test opportunity
  Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity( Name = 'My Test Opp1',
                              AccountId = testAcct.Id,
                              StageName = 'Closed Lost',
                              CloseDate = System.today().addDays(4));

  insert  testOpp;

   // Get the opportunity, verify the stage name and close date
  testOpp = [SELECT StageName, Name
             FROM Opportunity 
             WHERE id = :testOpp.Id];

  System.assertEquals(testOpp.StageName, 'Closed Lost');
  System.assertEquals(testOpp.Name, 'My Test Opp1');

  } 
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but apparently it happens from time to time because of ApexExecutionOverlayAction freaking out when you try to queue a test. Try setting "Disable Parallel Test Execution" under Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution | Options, and re-run the test, and see if it works. I don't see anything *wrong* with your code so far.

Comment: Also, the last answer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008w88IAA) suggests that if you have inactive stages, it can cause errors.

Comment: Probably not related to your error, but shouldn't your trigger also be executed before insert ?

Comment: sfdcfox I tried what you suggested as faras changing the Apex Test Execution Setting and nothing happened.  Still 70%.  I then remembered I need one more piece of criteria to the first IF statement in my trigger.  I made the first IF statement into what you see below:

if((trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != 'Closed Lost')
             && (opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost') && (opp.Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c == 'Competition'))

Comment: The Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c is a multiselect picklist field so maybe I need some type of contains?  Anyways after I added this new piece of criteria I couldn't save my trigger because I would receive the below Deployment error:
Deployment error:
An unexpected error has occurred. 59022395-181526 (749494588) for deploymentId=1drL0000000YbL9IAK If this persists, please contact customer support.

Comment: We do have inactive stages that are way old sitting there also sfdcfox. Should I delete those?  Thanks

Comment: Hi Samuel I don't think the trigger should also be executed before insert because we want the error message to display when a user moves an oppty to Closed Lost when the oppty doesn't have a competitor logged.  I think it would be just  before update?  What was your though behind before insert also?  Thanks

Comment: So I am back at were I started with the 70% coverage.  The Deployment error went away.  My new criteria works for the first IF statement after I modified it once more.
if(trigger.OldMap.get(opp.Id).StageName != 'Closed Lost'
             && (opp.StageName == 'Closed Lost') && (opp.Reasons_for_Lost_Opportunity__c.contains('Competition')))
Now I have this issue of only 70% code coverage.  How can I get that up to 75%?  The trigger works as I tested it in Sandbox.  It functions how I want it to but I need that extra 5% coverage to move it to Production.  Thanks again.